# Reconciling notations for mixed models

Tags: mixed-model, mathematical-statistics

I am familiar with notation such as:

\begin{align}
y_{ij} &= \beta_0 + \beta_i x_{ij} + u_j + e_{ij}\\
&= \beta_{0j} +  \beta_i x_{ij} + e_{ij}
\end{align}
where $\beta_{0j}=\beta_{0}+u_j$, and

\begin{align}
y_{ij} &= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{ij} + u_{0j} + u_{1j} x_{ij} + e_{ij} \\
&= \beta_{0j} +  \beta_{1j} x_{ij} + e_{ij}
\end{align}
where $\beta_{0j}=\beta_{0}+u_{0j}$ and $\beta_{1j}=\beta_1+u_{1j}$

for a random intercepts model and a random slope + random intercepts model, respectively.

I have also come across this matrix/vector notation, which I have been told is "mixed model notation for grown ups" (according to my elder brother):

$$
\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{X\beta} + \mathbf{Z b} + \mathbf{e}
$$
where $\mathbf{\beta}$ are the fixed effects and $\mathbf{b}$ are the random effects.

If I have understood correctly, the latter notation is a more general notation for the former which are specific versions of the latter.

I should like to see how the former can be derived from the latter.

Comment: Are you asking about an explanation of matrix notation?  The reason I ask is that this question doesn't need any mathematical derivation: all your formulas are saying exactly the same things and relating them to one another is just a matter of understanding how matrix notation works.

Comment: @whuber I understand matrix notation and matrix algebra, to some extent. But I don't know how to start from the matrix form and arrive at the other forms. Probably I don't understand something about the X and Z matrices, but I was just hoping that someone would spell it out.

Comment: @whuber is there something I can do to improve the question, or are you saying that it's so basic it doesn't deserve an answer ?

Comment: @JoeKing: I think that he's saying that the matrix notation is by definition equivalent to your non-matrix notation. That is, you already have $x_{ij}\beta_i$ (ixj matrix times jx1 matrix yielding ix1 matrix $y_i$) which is $y=X\beta$. (You can roll $\beta_0$ into $\beta$ by including a 1 in $X$.)

Comment: @Wayne thank you, both yourself and whuber I'm sure are correct, but nevertheless I don't understand. Do you realise how frustrating it is to ask a question only to be given a comment that the answer is obvious (and even more so for someone else to upvote the comment !), or just to be given bits of the answer. I get it about $\beta_0$ and a column is 1s in $X$, but how does $Z$ and $b$ relate to the 2 given specific models ?

Comment: @JoeKing: Do your first models have random effects only? In that case, $Zb$ corresponds to your $x_{ij}\beta_i$ and you have no equivalent of the $X\beta$ in the matrix version. It's really a matter of figuring out what are the fixed effects in your original equations and saying they correspond to the matrix multiplication of $X\beta$, and figuring what are the random effects in your original equations and saying they correspond to the matrix multiplication $Zb$. Then looking how matrix multiplication is expanded into subscripted vectors.

Comment: @Wayne both models have random effects and fixed effects. The first has a random intercept, while the second has a random intercept and a random slope. If I could "figure it out" myself I wouldn't be asking the question here  !!!!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We consider a mixed model with random slopes and random intercepts. Given that we have only one regressor, this model can be written as
$$ y_{ij}= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{ij} + u_{0j}+u_{1j}x_{ij}+\epsilon_{ij},
$$
where $y_{ij}$ denotes the $i$-th observation of group $j$ of the response, and $x_{ij}$  and $\epsilon_{ij}$ the respective predictor and error term.

This model can be expressed in matrix notation as follows:

$$\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{X}\beta + \textbf{Zb} + \epsilon,$$
which is equivalent to

$$\mathbf{Y}= \begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X} & \textbf{Z}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\beta\\ 
\mathbf{b}
\end{bmatrix}+ \epsilon $$

Let us assume that we have $J$ groups, i.e. $j=1,\dots,J$ and let $n_j$ denote the number of observations in the $j$-th group. Partitioned for each group, we can write above formula as

$$\begin{bmatrix}
 \mathbf{Y_1}
\\ \mathbf{Y_2}
\\ \vdots 
\\ \mathbf{Y_J}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\mathbf{X_1} & \mathbf{Z_1} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\mathbf{X_2} &  0 &  \mathbf{Z_2} & 0 & 0 \\ 
\vdots &  &  & \dots  &  \\ 
\mathbf{X_J} & 0 & 0  & 0 & \mathbf{Z_J}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\beta \\ 
b_1 \\ 
b_2 \\
\vdots \\ 
b_J 
\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_1 \\ 
\epsilon_2 \\ 
\vdots \\ 
\epsilon_J
\end{bmatrix}$$

where $\mathbf{Y_j}$ is a $n_j \times 1 $ matrix containing all observations of the response for group $j$, $\mathbf{X_j}$ and $\mathbf{Z_j}$ are $n_j \times 2 $ design matrices in this case and $\epsilon_j$ is again a $n_j \times 1 $ matrix.

Writing them out, we have:

$\mathbf{Y_j} = \begin{bmatrix}
y_{1j}\\ 
y_{2j}\\ 
\vdots \\ 
y_{n_jj}
\end{bmatrix},
\mathbf{X_j}=\mathbf{Z_j}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & x_{1j} \\ 
1 & x_{2j} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots \\ 
1 & x_{n_jj}
\end{bmatrix}$
and
$\epsilon_j = \begin{bmatrix}
\epsilon_{1j}\\ 
\epsilon_{2j}\\ 
\vdots \\ 
\epsilon_{n_jj}
\end{bmatrix}.$

The regression coefficient vectors then are

$\beta = \begin{pmatrix}
\beta_0 \\ 
\beta_1
\end{pmatrix}$,
$b_j=\begin{pmatrix}
u_{0j}\\ 
u_{1j}
\end{pmatrix}$

To see that the two model formulations are indeed equivalent, let us look at any of the groups  (let's say the $j$-th one).

$$ \mathbf{Y_j} = \mathbf{X_j} \beta + \mathbf{Z_j}b_j + \epsilon_j$$

Applying above definitions, one can show that the $i$-th row of the resulting vector is just 
$$ y_{ij}= \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{ij} + u_{0j}+u_{1j}x_{ij}+\epsilon_{ij},
$$
where $i$ ranges from $1$ to $n_j$.

Comment: +1, I would just point out that there are large computational advantages from implementing using $Z_j$ rather than the full $Z$ matrix.  The $Z_j$ are basically a sparse matrix storage version of $Z$